# scraping a table then writing to csv

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am pretty new to python and beautiful soup. this is my first 'real' project. I am trying to scrape some info from a website. So far I have been semi-successful. I have identified the table and got python to print out the relevant information pretty nicely.

I am stuck with writing that information python prints to a usable csv file.

here is what I have for my code. to get python to print the info I need.

```
for row in table_1.find_all('tr'):
    tds = row.find_all('td')
    try:
        a = str(tds[0].get_text())
        b = str(tds[1].get_text())
        c = str(tds[2].get_text())
        d = str(tds[3].get_text())
        e = str(tds[4].get_text())
        f = str(tds[5].get_text())
        g = str(tds[7].get_text())
        print 'User Name:' +  a
        print 'Source:' +  b
        print 'Staff:' +  c
        print 'Location:' +  d
        print 'Attended On:' +  e
        print 'Used:' +  f
        print 'Date:' +  g + '\n'


    except:
        print 'bad string'
        continue
```

Comment: Did you check out the csv library? https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more succinct way to collect your data:

```
columns = ["User Name", "Source", "Staff", "Location", "Attended On", "Used", "Date"]
table = []

for row in table_1.find_all('tr'):
    tds  = row.find_all('td')
    try:
        data = [td.get_text() for td in tds]
        for field,value in zip(columns, data):
            print("{}: {}".format(field, value))
        table.append(data)
    except:
        print("Bad string value")
```

and you can then write to csv as

```
import csv

with open("myfile.csv", "wb") as outf:                 # Python 2.x
# with open("myfile.csv", "w", newline="") as outf:    # Python 3.x
    outcsv = csv.writer(outf)

    # header row
    outcsv.writerow(columns)

    # data
    outcsv.writerows(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could append `a` thru `g` to a list within a list for each iteration of the loop. Then use this:

```
my_list = []
for row in table_1.find_all('tr'):
    tds = row.find_all('td')
    a = str(tds[0].get_text())
    b = str(tds[1].get_text())
    c = str(tds[2].get_text())
    d = str(tds[3].get_text())
    e = str(tds[4].get_text())
    f = str(tds[5].get_text())
    g = str(tds[7].get_text())
    my_list.append([a,b,c,d,e,f,g])
```

Then:

```
import csv
with open('output_table.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    wr= csv.writer(csvfile,lineterminator = '\n')
    wr.writerows(my_list)
```